# Sharepoint people picker in List Definition

Tags: people-picker, people-search

I have created a people picker in list definition. When I add an item to a list it is showing the `domain\username`. But I want firstname, lastname.

For example `Santosh, Kumar`

```
<Field ID="{DFD56BB9-1528-471A-824F-DCCEB90029A6}" Type="UserMulti" Name="PointOfContact" DisplayName="PointOfContact" Required="TRUE" UserSelectionMode="PeopleAndGroups" ShowField="Name" Mult="TRUE" Presence="TRUE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

How is your User Profile service configured? The Person column type saves something that looks like this:

> 23;#domain\username

Then SharePoint itself simply looks at your site collection, finds site user #23 (in this example), confirms that the username matches up, and then takes whatever info you've got there for their first and last name going forward. The site collection user list, in turn, just takes the information from your User Profile Service (there's a timer job that disseminates that info that runs hourly by default).

If you haven't set up User Profile Services, or if for some reason you aren't importing names, or if the login isn't on the list of imported items into UPS (for instance, if you've got multiple AD forests but are only pulling from a couple of them in UPS but you've configured your PeoplePicker via stsadm to pull from more), you might only see the login there. It's also possible that your site collection's entry for that login just didn't include the first and last name (for instance, if the user was added before you configured UPS).

Either way, if it's just one user you can always just edit the site collection user entry itself. If it's multiple people, I'm guessing that it's an issue with UPS.

Comment: John,Thanks for your detailed explanation. I have my Firstname,Lastname configured in AD. I want to set the ShowField option of the People picker to (NamewithPresence)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your list using browser. On list settings, click your column. On "additional column settings" section, there is a combobox which shows the field to display.

Comment: Thanks i am creating the list from the list definition. I want to set it automatically any idea

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "ShowField" parameter in your XML.

By default, ShowField goes to NameWithPresence.

You could also try to override its value.